# Alternative to IdeaTorrent (web application with thumb-up feature)?

Tags: collaboration

I am searching for a collaborative web application with a ***thumb-up like voting system***. This will be used by users/developers/managers of an application to ***vote for their favorite feature and comment on it***. This will then feed the software development backlog.

I have found [IdeaTorrent](http://www.ideatorrent.org), but it is linked to the Drupal system. 
I would like to find another simple and standalone web application.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

EDIT

I've found this link http://alternativeto.net/software/ideatorrent/, with has a bunch of tools, however, they are too general and/or too oriented for users.

Answer (score 2):

A simple alternative is [Google Moderator](https://www.google.com/moderator/), especially if your users already have Google accounts.

Users can submit new features ("questions"), and other users can vote them up or down.